# How to return unique values from Google Places API?

Tags: python, google-api

I'm making a request from Google Places API with a query "Hotels in Brazil", with the following code:

```
# url variable store url 
url = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/textsearch/json?"

# The text string on which to search 
query = input('Search query: ') 

# get method of requests module 
# return response object 
r = requests.get(url + 'query=' + query +
                        '&key=' + api_key + 
                        '&maxResults=1000') 

# json method of response object convert 
x = r.json() 

# store the value of result key in variable y 
y = x['results'] 

#Getting information from other pages with "next_page_token" param
places=[]

params = {
    'query': query, 
    'key' : api_key,
    'maxResults': '1000'
}

while "next_page_token" in x:
    params['pageToken'] = x['next_page_token'],
    res = requests.get(url, params = params)
    z = json.loads(res.content)
    places.extend(z['results'])


print(places)
```

But it's taking too long to return the results ( more than 1 day). So i stopped the execution and when i printed it, i got many repeated names, for an example, i got 16K places but only 26 unique places.

Is it possible to return unique values from Google Places API?

Comment: Your problem is that you are not updating the value for `x` so you are just requesting the second page forever!

Comment: @n1rna So, do i need to change the z var for x, in the while statement?

Comment: I can't just simply answer with `Yes` cause that's too short :)